# How to populate StringEdit based on another StringEdit value?

Tags: axapta, x++

I have 2 StringEdit controls in my form. Each StringEdit control has different DataSources(DataField as A), like DataSource1 and DataSource2(DataFiled as X). The data in these dources looks as follows:
DataSource1  DataSource2
A   B        X       Y
==========   ===========
A1  B1       X1      Y1
A2  B2       X2      Y2
A3  B3       X3      Y3
A4  B4       X4      Y4

Now I have another table which contains mappings for A in DataSource1 and X in DataSource2, where values in A mapped to single or multiple values of X. It looks like as follows:

DataSource3

## A       X

A1      X1
A1      X2
A2      X2
A3      X3
A3      X4
A4      X4

Now, the requirement is as follows:
When I select a value in StringEdit1, based on the selected values and mappings from DataSource3 if the selected value in StringEdit1 control has only one mapping in DataSource3 then the corresponding X value should get populated in StringEdit2 control.

In the modified method of the StringEdit1 control I have tried the following approach: 
1. I get the selected value from StringEdit1 control using StringEdit1.valueStr()
2. I write a query to get the mapped values of the selected value from dataSource3.
3. Then I am checking whether it contains only one value and assigning that value to StringEdit2 control using StringEdit2.text(mappedValue);

But it is not showing the value in the StringEdit2 control.

I expect the mappedValue be displayed in StringEdit2 control. But it is not showing. Please help me with this.

Comment: Could you [edit] the code of the steps 1. to 3. into your question? Could you also check the formatting of the parts where you describe the data sources?

Comment: Could you show us the code please?, If you debug mappedValue have a value?